# matlab legend entries from loop don't show up in legend

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Commented code does not work, uncommented code works. Why can I not specify which line objects should be included in the legend if the lines where plotted in a loop?

```
labels = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'}
% for i = 1:7
%     [~, I] = min( abs(A - B(i)) );
%     h(i) = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(i,:));
% end
% legend( h, labels, 'Location', 'NorthEast');
[~, I] = min( abs(A - B(1)) );
h1 = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(1,:));
[~, I] = min( abs(A - B(2)) );
h2 = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(2,:));
[~, I] = min( abs(A - B(3)) );
h3 = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(3,:));
[~, I] = min( abs(A - B(4)) );
h4 = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(4,:));
[~, I] = min( abs(A - B(5)) );
h5 = plot(T, Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(5,:));
[~, I] = min( abs(A - B(6)) );
h6 = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(6,:));
[~, I] = min( abs(A - B(7)) );
h7 = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(7,:));
legend([h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7], labels, 'Location', 'NorthEast');
```

Comment: Before claiming that Matlab's plotting functionality is "crappy" you should be sure it's not a problem with your code. And in that regard we cannot help unless your code is runnable as is, which now it isn't. Please define `A`, `B`, `T`, `Z`, `ax1`, `colors` that reproduce the problem. Let me know when you do so I can remove my downvote

Comment: Also, which version of Matlab are you using? I don't seem to be able to reproduce the error on 2019b. What is the error message?

Comment: Of course there is a problem with my code. That doesn't change the fact that MathWorks plotting implementation has been neglected for over 30 years. At least they've finally demonstrated a, partial, understanding of OOP with changes in 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

legend(target,___) uses the axes or chart(**not the handles of line series**) specified by target instead of the current axes or chart. Specify the target as the first input argument. You can find more detailed description [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#d120e695460). So in your code:

```
legend(h,__)
```

should be

```
legend(ax1,__)
```

or simply

```
legend(gca,__)
```

More generally, there are some solutions more readable& commonly used:

### Solution #1 : specify DisplayName of each line.

```
for i = 1:7
 [~, I] = min( abs(A - B(i)) );
 h(i) = plot(T(:,I), Z, '-', 'Parent', ax1, 'color', colors(i,:),'DisplayName',labels{i});end;legend on
```

### Solution #2 : call legend(labels) directly

```
labels = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'}
x = 1:100;
axes(ax1) % specify which axes the next plot should use
for i = 1:7
    plot(x,rand(size(x)));
    hold on
end
hold off
legend(labels, 'Location', 'NorthEast');
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Comment: ```'DisplayName',labels{i}``` That's the ticket! Thanks Shannon Chow.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've added more detailed explanation. Thx!